# How to host 2 domain names on the same server in iis7?

Tags: iis-7

I have a virtual dedicated server, I want to host 2 domain names on the same server, I have windows server 2008 (iis 7). how do I make 2 domain names point to 2 differents Web sites on this server ?

Answer (score 1):

A great site to follow up on

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-in-iis-70/

Answer (score 0):

You setup the http headers of the virtual folder
so the http server knows which http address goes to which virtual folder.