# How to set up 2 domain name pointing to 2 different folders on the same server?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have 2 domain names registered.
I also have 1 server at AWS. (running Ubuntu)

I would like to host 2 websites on my server but have no clue how to do it.

I have two directories `/var/www/alpha` and `/var/www/beta`  for each domain.

alpha DNS is already configured to work with `www.mywebsite.co` and `mywebsite.co` and so on.

I'm very new to admin systems any help would be much appreciated.

I've looked online and found this thread: 
[How to host 2 domain names on the same server in iis7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/87028/how-to-host-2-domain-names-on-the-same-server-in-iis7)

where a guy say:

> You setup the http headers of the virtual folder so the http server
>   knows which http address goes to which virtual folder.

Is it the way to follow ? I don't know how to do that.

Many thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a VirtualHost configuration.

> Virtual Hosts are used to run more than one domain off of a single IP
>   address. This is especially useful to people who need to run several
>   sites off of one virtual private server. The sites display different
>   information to the visitors, depending on with which the users
>   accessed the site.There is no limit to the number of virtual hosts
>   that can be added to a VPS.

Take a look in these links:

[Virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)

[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)